# Linq query returns no result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select

I am trying to get a sublist from a list by condition (both Observable collections). While this works as expected - selects few results:

```
ObservableCollection<TestCase> affectedTestCases =
    new ObservableCollection<TestCase>();
foreach (var testCase in TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases)
{
    if (testCase.TestHash == CurrentFile.Hash)
    {
        affectedTestCases.Add(testCase);
    }
}
```

where Hash (and TestHash) is a simple string. This one does not show results and I wonder why:

```
var affectedTestCases = from testCase in TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases
where testCase.TestHash==CurrentFile.Hash
select testCase;
```

Then I wanted to use the results by:

```
foreach (var affectedTestCase in affectedTestCases)
```

But it does not show any for the LINQ variant. I also tried casting AffectedTestCases to list. And I also tried using String.Equals() for comparison. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: LINQ code is OK (but it isn't equivalent of `foreach` one). Please, show more code, where query results are being used.

Comment: Have you walked through the code in the debugger? Are you sure in the second case that `TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases` actually has anything in it? Are you sure the collection contains a value for `TestHash` that is equal to `CurrentFile.Hash`? Your LINQ query should work as-is (you *do not* need to add a `ToList`) so something must be wrong with your data set.

Comment: TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases contains 4 items, where 3 of them have the same TestHash as CurrentFile.Hash. I try to run those two pieces of code in one function without changing the data set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var affectedTestCases = TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases.Where(_ => _.TestHash.Equals(CurrentFile.Hash));
```

Comment: What have you changed? Only a code dump isn't really useful.

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection It implements Collection Strange if its not working , slightly modified using Any() please try this

```
 var affectedTestCases = from testCase in TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases
                                 where TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases.Any(o=> o.TestHash.Contains(CurrentFile.Hash))
                                 select testCase ;
```

OR

```
 affectedTestCases = new ObservableCollection<TestCase>(TestCaseList.Where(o => o.TestHash.Any(m => m.Equals(CurrentFile.TestHash))).Select(o => o));
```

Comment: Second version does not work: CS1061: 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, I tried to use LINQ and then I modified CurrentFile.Hash (part of LINQ condition). And after that the foreach on affectedTestCases shows no results. So I used the LINQ wrong, because I changed the condition. I assumed It remembers the results. Solution is simple, I can use ToList() on the result of LINQ and use these results. Something like this:

```
var affectedTestCases = (from testCase in TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases
  where testCase.TestHash==CurrentFile.Hash
  select testCase).ToList();

ScriptEditor.Save(filePath);// this changes CurrentFile.Hash

foreach (var affectedTestCase in affectedTestCases2)
{
  int index = TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases.IndexOf(affectedTestCase);
  TestCaseList.ListOfTestCases[index].TestHash = CurrentFile.Hash;
}
```

Thanks for the help. I wouldn't figured it out otherwise.